# escape/replace apostrophe is not working

Tags: android, replace, android-sqlite

I am using the following line

```
memo = etMemo.getText().toString().replace("'", "\'");
```

because apostrophes are causing errors in my app.  Even doing this replace though, I am still receiving an error.

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO [Trst](credit, memo, timestamp) VALUES ('10.0', 'Test's', '07/29/2014')

Does anyone know why this wouldnt be working properly?

Comment: Consider using parameters in your SQL to avoid the need for escaping apostrophes and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
memo = etMemo.getText().toString().replace("'", "\'\'"); // one apostrophe -> two apostrophes
```